# Run mocha with Typescript throws: TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

I'm trying to write some tests with Typescript and [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/).

Following its documentation I ended up with the following setup:

*package.json*

```json
{
//...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
  },
//...
}
```

*.mocharc.json*

```json
{
  "extension": ["test.ts"],
  "spec": "tests/*.test.ts",
  "require": "ts-node/register",
  "recursive": true
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
    },
    "files": [
        "src/main/main.ts",
    ],
}
```

Running `npm test` throws the following error: `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for [...]/tests/task.test.ts`.

That is my only test, and it works until I import a separate `.ts` file (`../src/core/task`), for completeness:

*task.test.ts*

```js
import { assert } from 'chai';
import { Task } from '../src/core/task';

describe('Task', () => {
    it('Task Run', () => {
        const task = new Task({
            title: "My Title",
            command: "echo hello",
            path: "."
        });
        
        task.run();
    })
});
```

I have tried several permutations of my config according to some other answers as well as `ts-mocha` without success.

Comment: After fiddling with this for a bit, I noticed that the issue is an ESM-only library that was being imported by `core/task`. In order to make it work it seems I would need to port the project to ESM. Not sure if there are easier alternatives

Answer (score 6):

I have same problem before it work in ts-node@9 but not in ts-node@10 and then i tried this configuration in `.mocharc.json` to make it work as expected

```
{
  "extensions": ["ts"],
  "spec": ["**/*.spec.*"],
  "node-option": [
    "experimental-specifier-resolution=node",
    "loader=ts-node/esm"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm having same issue.  I'm new to mocha unit tests and I'm a little confused.  There is a mocharc.json file in the mocha lib folder.  Do you modify that file or create a new one in your project? Thank you.

Comment: @Patricia you can create new file `.mocharc.json` in your project root, you can check how i used it in this repo https://github.com/point-hub/express-factory/tree/v1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was caused by an `import` in a JS file imported by TypeScript test files. Transforming it to a require fixed the problem.

Generally speaking, when the exception occurs in:

`Loader.defaultGetFormat [as _getFormat] internal/modules/esm/get_format.js`

there can be only one explanation: Node.js is using its ESM loader to load what should be code transpiled by `ts-node`.

So the fix should always be - find the reason Node.js is switching to ESM and eliminate it.

Comment: Removing import is a workaround; not an answer. You just converted your entire project from ESM to CJS.

Comment: :-)
Maybe you didn't read, the answer, maybe you didn't read the question, maybe you don't know what you are talking about
The question is about TypeScript, not JS, if you want to transpile your TS to ES6 you need to set a lot of options and do a lot of things that are out of scope for this question. TS is usually transpiled to CJS.